# MongoDB : alter an existing index on a collection

Tags: mongodb

We are using MongoDB for our Application .
I see that an indexes are already present for the collections .

We had a new requirement , for which i see that the response is very slow from MongoDB  for some of the opeartioons.

I want to  add an  extra field to the existing index , without dropping the existing index .

Please tell me if this is possible or not .

Will this have any impact on the Application ??

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can't alter indexes once they have been created.

You could easily create a new index that would cover the new field.

Adding indexes is very easy from the shell you can type

```
db.yourcollection.ensureIndex( { field1: 1, field2: -1 } )
```

Mongo will look at your indexes and work out which one is best to use for your query. You can see this by adding explain onto the end of your query in the shell, this will tell you if it used an index and what index was used.

This will also be a good tool for working out what is slow about your query.

See the Mongo Documentation for further details http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/